# ndiffs for Python

Tags: python, r, time-series

Is there a function equivalent of `R`'s `ndiffs` function in `Python`? 
It is used to estimate a number of diffs for creating stationary time-series.

[R Documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.1/topics/ndiffs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function implemented in [pmdarima](http://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/1.5.1/modules/classes.html) that can help you finding the number of diffs.

The function is called [pmdarima.arima.ndiffs](http://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/1.5.1/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.ndiffs.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there any is any library that can directly make your data stationary in python. However, you can plot your time series, which will visually tell you the components such as trend and seasonality of your data.

using `statsmodel` you can take each a look at each component of a time-series like this,

```
trend = decomposition.trend
seasonal = decomposition.seasonal 
residual = decomposition.residual
```

After this you can use `shift` function to make your time-series stationary by taking off trend and seasonality.

Refer to this [tutorial](http://www.seanabu.com/2016/03/22/time-series-seasonal-ARIMA-model-in-python/), which has in detail to make your time-series stationary based on your data. Hope this helps.